# A dataset with Int64, Float64 and datetime64[ns] gets converted to object after applying Pandas fillna method

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I am using Kaggle's dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/claytonmiller/lbnl-automated-fault-detection-for-buildings-data)

I have A dataset with Int64, Float64, and datetime64[ns] datatypes; after using the pandas fillna method, however, all of my data type changes to object datatype.

Could anyone assist me with what I need to do to retain the original data types after the Pandas conversion?

The following is the code I use:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv('RTU.csv') 
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
```

[image: The data types initally]

If I do a `df.dtypes` I can see the correct datatypes however, after the following lines of code, it changes to object datatype.

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
def fault_mapper_FD(faultDate):
    if pd.Timestamp(2017, 8, 27, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 8, 28, 0):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2017, 8, 29, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 8, 29, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 1, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 1, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 3, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 3, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 7, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 8, 0):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 14, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 14, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 7, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 7, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 9, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 9, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 20, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 20, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 18, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 18, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 1, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 1, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 31, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 31, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 28, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 28, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 27, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2018, 1, 27, 23, 59):
        return 0
    if (pd.Timestamp(2017, 9, 1, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 9, 1, 23, 59) or 
    pd.Timestamp(2017, 11, 30, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 11, 30, 23, 59) or 
    pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 9, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 9, 23, 59) or 
    pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 10, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 11, 0) or 
    pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 24, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2017, 12, 24, 23, 59) or 
    pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 4, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 4, 23, 59) or 
    pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 5, 0) <= faultDate <= pd.Timestamp(2018, 2, 6, 0)):
        return 1

df['FD'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda fault_date: fault_mapper_FD(fault_date))

cond = (df.Timestamp.dt.time > dt.time(22,0)) | ((df.Timestamp.dt.time < dt.time(7,0)))
df[cond] = df[cond].fillna(0,axis=1)
```

Now the `df.dtypes` gives all of my columns as objects/

[image: The data types after the Pandas fillna methos]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a small typo. You just need to call

```
df = df[cond].fillna(0,axis=0)
```

which indeed doesn't change datatypes

```
Timestamp                               datetime64[ns]
RTU: Supply Air Temperature                    float64
RTU: Return Air Temperature                    float64
RTU: Supply Air Fan Status                       int64
RTU: Circuit 1 Discharge Temperature           float64
                                             ...      
VAV Box: Room 203 Air Temperature              float64
VAV Box: Room 204 Air Temperature              float64
VAV Box: Room 205 Air Temperature              float64
VAV Box: Room 206 Air Temperature              float64
Fault Detection Ground Truth                     int64
Length: 69, dtype: object
```

Comment: @ Nuri Taş, yes it works on the partial one, however I have another one condition that does not work with changing axis and gives df[cond] = df[cond].fillna(0,axis=0 # added inplace = True , df[cond] = df[cond].fillna(0,axis=1,inplace = True) when adding this all becomes float
                                                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: I don't understand why you write **df[cond] = df[cond].fillna(0,axis=0, inplace = True]** instead of **df = df[cond] = df[cond].fillna(0,axis=0, inplace = True]**. The second thing is , as the error clearly says, you probably have an indentation error in your code.  You can implement the two conditions at the same time by calling **df = df[cond_1 &  cond_2].fillna(0, axis=0)**

Comment: @ Nuri Taş,, yes it works when I make it  df[cond].fillna(0,axis=0, inplace = True). However gives me this warning A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df[cond].fillna(0,axis=0, inplace = True). Can you tell me why?

Comment: Because you both filter out the dataframe by a condition and also apply **inplace = True**, meaning you try to inplace the newly created dataframe into the old dataframe.The code **df = df[cond_1 & cond_2].fillna(0, axis=0)** shouldn't raise any error